# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, excel, исключения

Я пытаюсь открыть файл xlsx с помощью

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseCdataLiteral(PiccoloLexer.java:3027)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseQuotedTagValue(PiccoloLexer.java:2936)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1754)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseXMLNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1293)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseXML(PiccoloLexer.java:1261)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4812)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3479)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:196)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:188)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:378)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:166)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:271)
    at TestFavorit.main(TestFavorit.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Размер файла: ~50 мб
В интернетах пишут что можно запустить приложение с опцией, например -Xmx1024m. Как это сделать в intellij idea и какой размер нужно указывать для файла 50мб?

Comment: что то мне подсказывает что добавить памяти тут не поможет.

Comment: по теме-в конфигурации запуска или отладки есть поле аргуметов виртуальной машины, это туда

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А что тогда может помочь?

Comment: может это http://web.archive.org/web/20110821054135/http://www.realdevelopers.com/blog/code/excel

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, я ничего не понял. Ни зачем там zip ни зачем xml, но я скопировал пример BigGridDemo и запустил, сгенерировался файл со 100к сроками всего за пару секунд, может быть, если разобраться, то это решит проблему

Comment: потому что это зазипованный xml

Comment: как раз добавление памяти в этом случае  может помочь (разумеется, если это не утечка памяти в вашем коде). а вообще для начала попробуйте поднять версию poi до 4 (лучше до последней). с высокой вероятностью, если версия 4 работать не будет, то это проблема вашего кода.